# Pandas.Dataframe stop filling table and then continue

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interrupt, data-analysis

I have a pandas.dataframe with count of rows about `1500000`.

I wrote a function that processes a data set and fill each column in one row of the table.

I am trying to determine the best way to accomplish task: **when I force stop my python script that runs the filling function, how to save the current incomplete table? and the next time filling function loads the table and continue filling on the row, which has been stopped (ideally even column which was stopped).**

I think I need to catch `KeyboardInterrupt` exception and save the table with method `pandas.to_csv('temp.csv')` and at the beginning of my filling function check if `'temp.csv'` exists. **But how to determine for what the row (and column in this row) I need to start filling, and this kind of interruption safe?**

Comment: Please, show an example of data and algo

Comment: I don't think pandas is ideal for this sort of behavior. If there is no dependence between the rows, you may want to look into reading your file row by row, and writing to another file in parallel. This way, if the process is interrupted, the partial data was already written. Then, before you restart your process, you count the number of rows in the partial file, and start from that point (taking into consideration that this last row may only be partial, and should probably be overwritten).

Comment: Are you just using Pandas as a results data-structure at this point?  It's not really a Pandas question.  I think as you're already thinking, you might want to save the results of each processed data set, adding the results to a csv file, keeping track of which data sets have been processed.  You can then read in the completed csv file into a Pandas data structure and do your analysis.